# Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V - High Availability (Clustering): Connect servers to storage using FC: switch or direct attach?

Tags: storage-area-network, failovercluster, fiber, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

My scenario:

I have a DS3400 DISK SYSTEM DUAL CONTROLLER FIBRE CHANNEL storage equipped with two controllers each equipped with two 4-GBPS FC ports, for a total of four FC ports.

Then I have four servers each equipped with one IBM 4-GBPS FC SINGLE-PORT PCI-E HBA card.

I'm trying to setup a Windows 2012-R2 Hyper-V cluster.

It is sufficient that I connect each server to one of the four FC ports of the DS3400 or I need some sort of FC switch to obtain the fact that if one storage's controller crash the cluster still obtain access to the storage ?

Thank you for any support !

Ivano C.

Comment: What if your FC switch becomes defective?

Comment: `It is sufficient that I connect each server to one of the four FC ports of the DS3400` - You can't connect all four servers directly to the storage array. You can connect two servers directly to the storage array. It seems like you will need an FC switch if you want all 4 servers to connect to the storage array. Read the PDF in the first Google result here: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=DS3400+cabling

Comment: @joeqwerty I think you gave me the righ direction. I need to explore the use of one or two switches to realize a really fault tolerant configuration. Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to connect all 4 directly to the storage array. An FC switch is needed. Pages 43 and 44 in the linked document describes this. - http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitzKmrmtfLAhXMJB4KHbI-D1UQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redbooks.ibm.com%2Fredbooks%2Fpdfs%2Fsg247065.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFxNYDuYhsUlNwWhtDTM3G12GYTDw&sig2=wJfskbbzG0QZdvigOVildw

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DS3400 manual](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/46m1394.pdf) you can direct attach, you don't need an FC switch - that said some arrays don't like this method so it was worth checking. The single-port-ed-ness worries me by the way but I guess you know the risks.